# Location tagging facebook open graph actions so that only friends in that location view in their feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to tag open graph actions so as to target certain recipients and not others?

For example, if my app talks about new coffee shop openings in various cities, is there a way to publish the 'opening' action to the graph, perhaps with location / coordinates, such that this is only seen by friends in that locality? I really don't want to spam my friends in London about an opening I'm excited about in Portland. How can I help facebook with the feed relevance in these cases?

I noticed that there is a "place" property on open graph objects - could this somehow be used?

Comment: Facebook just added this feature:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this today. The closest thing would be to define custom privacy per action published, but you'd have to manually choose the users that you thought would be interested. See more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publish-action/.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook just added this feature: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/05/platform-updates--new-open-graph-business-object-type/

Although I haven't seen the effects of using a business object vs a regular object on feeds, I believe their goal is to show these OG actions only to people in the vicinity of where the action is happening.